# printing a huge matrix row-by-row

Tags: matlab, matrix, printf

I have a huge 2D matrix, symbolizing the count of files with certain name numberpattern in a directory.

To print this, I went about transforming this data into a cell array of individual strings and replace all `'0'` with empty strings. However this is wildly inefficient. Any advice **how to make this faster**?

```
data=randi([0 10],4000,27); %4000 matching number patterns, 27 directories, 0-10 counts
tic;
str=arrayfun(@num2str,data,'uni',0); %get string of the count
str2 = cellfun(@(x)regexprep(x,'^0$',' '),str,'uni',0); %replace 0 with ' '
toc
%takes around 2.0 to 2.5 seconds on my machine... too long!!
```

the idea is then to print it

```
for row=1:size(data,1)
  fprintf('%3s',str2{row,:})
  fprintf('\n')
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This avoids creating the cell array, and uses [`strrep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) instead of `regexp`:

```
data = randi([0 10], 4000, 27); % 0-10 counts
for row = 1:size(data, 1)
    disp(strrep(sprintf('%3i', data(row, :)), ' 0', '  '))
end
```

Comment: much faster, thank you, about one order of magnitude.